# overflow: hidden on div and body, different behavior

Tags: css, html, overflow

Given this html:

```
<body>
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
</body>
```

I want `#b` to fill all the remaining vertical space of its container block, I began with this:

```
body {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#b {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

So `#b` is 100% height, which means that it is taking the height of its parent container block, which is `500px`, the problem is that the `overflow: hidden;` seems to not work, `#b` is not clipped.

On the other hand, if I wrap `#a` and `#b` with another div with the same properties as `body` above I have the desired result:

```
#wrap {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#b {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

with this html of course:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

My question is why `div` and `body` seems to have different behaviors with the same properties? and is there any way to get the same effect without the wrapper?

To illustrate the question I have created two jsFiddles:

jsFiddle with body tag as wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/3AMtG/

jsFiddle with div tag as wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/2QWn3/

Two jsFiddles with the same properties yield different results.  Why is that?

Comment: i can´t see any difference between your two exaples, and thats maybe the point, i guess a body tag has a more basical value than a div tag and every browser has its own way to render etc           @Firefox 19.0.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `overflow` property has certain special behaviors specific to HTML's `html` and `body` elements, which are described in the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html). These special cases are in place to accommodate changing overflow settings on the entire page in normal circumstances so authors simply need to set it on either `html` or `body`, but not both.

In this case, when you apply `overflow: hidden` to `body`, it actually affects the viewport instead of `body` (you can see this by resizing the preview pane to make it shorter — no scrollbars will appear on the preview pane itself). This causes `#b` to overflow the body normally even though you give it a fixed height that's less than the sum of `#a` and `#b`. In other words, it's as though you never set it on the body in the first place.

If you set `overflow` to something other than `visible` on `html`, though, this causes the viewport to use the value given to `html` instead of `body`, thereby leaving the declaration on `body` unaffected and allowing it to behave the same way as the wrapper:

```
html {
  overflow: auto;
}

body {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/3AMtG/3)

Answer (score 0):

body and div have totally different of them. In my daily working, I like constructing my code like this.

```
<div class='xxx-ctn'>
  <div class='xxx-inner'>
    <div class='data-wrapper'>
      [p|ul|ol|h1-h6|article|section].....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Okey, I missing your founding, but I think this is a good coding habbit.

Answer (score 0):

Body element is considered as main parent element inside which other elements that are displayed within the browser window resides therefore, width and height property is not applicable onto it. According to the best practices it is better to create a div container like #wrapper that you did in your second example.